# How do I modify the MediaWiki CharInsert extension to enable the insertion of wikitext different from the button it provides?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

The [MediaWiki CharInsert extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CharInsert) is an extension that enables the usage of `<charinsert></charinsert>` tags on Wiki pages. These tags provide a JavaScript popup to allow the insertion of set pieces of wikitext into articles. It also creates a Wiki page called `MediaWiki:Edittools` on which users can add, within charinsert tags, pieces of wikitext they can insert into Wiki pages with a single click. I have difficulty explaining this clearly so I'm going to use the below screenshot to help me explain it.

This is the WYSIWIG wiki text editor, with the edittools toolbox shown. If you click on any of the buttons (e.g., the `<nowiki></nowiki>` one) it will insert the wikitext shown in the button you click into the WYSIWIG editor shown above.

[image]

Now the reason for this question is that I'd like to be able to modify the CharInsert extension so that it's possible to insert different wikitext than that used for the displayed title for the JavaScript (JS) button. One way I thought this could be done, would be to add an attribute, say "content". I am mentioning this because it helps me explain what I mean, say for example the Edittools page includes a line:

```
<charinsert content = "{{Information%0A|Description=%0A|Source=%0A|Date=%0A|License=%0A|Author=%0A}}">{{Information}}</charinsert>
```

then, while only `{{Information}}` would appear in the edittools toolbox, `{{Information%0A|Description=%0A|Source=%0A|Date=%0A|License=%0A|Author=%0A}}` would be what this button would insert into the WYSIWIG editor.

Does anyone know how I would modify the CharInsert extension to enable it to do this? Keeping in mind I know little about PHP, so please don't give me some programmer discourse that would be helpful to an experienced PHP programmer but useless to a novice like me. So please give me simple instructions of exactly what to add to which (i.e., you tell me which) PHP script file.

I have asked this question on the [Extension_Talk:CharInsert](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:CharInsert#Feature_request:_Accesskey_35114) page at MediaWiki.org, which sent me to [this](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T25354) issue on Phabricator and I tried the technique mentioned in the patch provided but it did not work (see the charinsert talk page for details, this was a while ago so I can't remember them off hand), probably because of how old this patch is (~5 years now). I am asking this question here months later as I still haven't received a useful reply.

If relevant I am using MediaWiki 1.25.1.

Comment: This seems like a good question, but you might want to edit it to split the proposed implementation details ("content" attribute) from the actual goal you want to accomplish (adding a charinsert button to the editor that inserts something other than its label), and focus on the latter. For all I know, the eventual solution might not involve a "content" attribute at all.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Not fully getting your comment (don't blame you, I know this topic isn't easy to explain). I think you mean, that I should generalize this question, removing the "content" attribute part and just asking how I can create a button that inserts wikitext other than that used as the title for the button. If so I added the content attribute because, as I understand it, SE websites like this one like questions to be as specific as possible and I'm on the verge of loosing question-asking privileges as it is here, hence I was being cautious but if you think it will help, I'll do it.

Comment: I agree that finding the best level of generality for asking a question can sometimes be difficult. Still, it's usually best to avoid falling into the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. asking about your proposed solution instead of the original problem. (You did at least *also* mention the original problem, which is much better than some cases I've seen.) For more tips, see the linked post above, as well as ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the SO help center.

Comment: I think I may have successfully edited the question the way you suggested, but I'm finding it difficult to generalize the question the way you recommend without making the question difficult to understand.

Comment: This looks better, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, having taken a closer look at the [CharInsert extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CharInsert) and its [source code](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fextensions%2FCharInsert/HEAD/CharInsert.body.php), I'd recommend just not using it.  It's klugy as heck, and it does nothing that couldn't be more easily done with JavaScript.

So, here's my suggestion:

#### 1. Add the following code to your MediaWiki:Common.js page:

```
// Turn <span class="mw-charinsert">foo</span> into a link that inserts "foo"
// into the edit box:
$( function () {
    $('span.mw-charinsert').wrap( '<a href="#">' ).click( function () {
        var text = this.title || this.textContent;
        var parts = text.split( '+' );
        if ( text === '+' ) parts = [ text ];
        var front = decodeURIComponent( parts[0] || '' );
        var back  = decodeURIComponent( parts[1] || '' );
        insertTags( front, back, '' );
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

#### 2. Replace your <charinsert> tags with <span class="mw-charinsert">:

This should mostly be a drop-in replacement; just convert:

```
<charinsert>foo</charinsert>
<charinsert>bar</charinsert>
```

into:

```
<span class="mw-charinsert">foo</span>
<span class="mw-charinsert">bar</span>
```

Note that, unlike the CharInsert extension, the JS code above does not support multiple whitespace-separated links in one tag.  That is,

```
<span class="mw-charinsert">foo bar</span>
```

creates a single link that inserts `foo bar`, not two links that insert `foo` and `bar` (but see below for a note about collapsing whitespace!).  You'll still want to wrap any text that contains wiki markup inside `<nowiki>` tags to protect it from parsing.

#### 3. Optionally, add title attributes to change the inserted text:

For example, to create a link that reads `foo` but inserts `bar`, use the following markup:

```
<span class="mw-charinsert" title="bar">foo</span>
```

Note that, as with the CharInsert extension, you can use a `+` sign in the inserted text to mark the position where the cursor (and any selected text) will be placed.

Note: It seems that MediaWiki (or, more likely, HTML Tidy) collapses consecutive whitespace inside titles and text.  I've added a kluge that URL-decodes the inserted text, so that you can represent literal spaces with `%20`, newlines with `%0A`, and plus signs with `%2B`.  This does mean that you'll also need to replace any literal `%` signs with `%25`.

---

**Ps.** The code above is *not* compatible with the [EditTools gadget](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-Edittools.js), or more specifically, with its `makeButtons()` function that tries to convert standard CharInsert links into buttons.  Here's a variant that turns `<span class="mw-charinsert">` elements directly into buttons, and *is* compatible with the gadget:

```
// Turn <span class="mw-charinsert">foo</span> into a button that inserts "foo"
// into the edit box:
$( function () {
    $( 'span.mw-charinsert' ).wrap( function () {
        var text = this.title || this.textContent;
        var parts = text.split( '+' );
        if ( text === '+' ) parts = [ text ];
        var front = decodeURIComponent( parts[0] || '' );
        var back  = decodeURIComponent( parts[1] || '' );
        return $( '<button>' ).click( function () {
            insertTags( front, back, '' );
            return false;
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I just tested it with the Edittools gadget. Here's the rendering: http://i.imgur.com/QorN0Qb.png. Here's the wikitext I switched over to your span tags: `<span class = "mw-charinsert" title = "{{FileBox%0A|code=%0A|lang=%0A|filename=%0A}}">{{FileBox}}</span> ·
<span class = "mw-charinsert" title = "{{PreBox%0A|1=%0A|lang=%0A|title=%0A|label=%0A|labelcolour=%0A|size=%0A}}">{{PreBox}}</span>`

Comment: Adding this JS code to the top of MediaWiki:Gadget-Edittools.js & removing it from MediaWiki:Common.js, I'm afraid doesn't change this rendering issue I'm experiencing btw, I just tried it.

Comment: Adding the `<nowiki>` tags where you recommended while it fixed the cosmetic issue (i.e., everything looks fine), when I click on the buttons produced by the span tags no wikitext was inserted. `<charinsert>` lines have no such rendering issue.

Comment: Ah, I'm not just a novice in PHP I'm also a JS novice. If it helps here's the console that pops up by right-clicking the {{FileBox}} button and selecting "Inspect Element": http://i.imgur.com/5rE2qV4.png.

Comment: Ah thanks, but those `%0A` characters are meant to be converted to new lines and while this modification is working in inserting the code it isn't parsing the `%0A` properly, it's leaving it unrendered.

Comment: Normal new lines don't do this I'm afraid, rather it just adds a single space in place of new lines. For FileBox, this is what is inserted `{{FileBox |code = |lang = |filename = }}` where there's a new line between each input (FileBox (new line) |code = (newline)...). Oh and I tried to make the equal signs for each input to line up, and many of the spaces I added in order to achieve this was missing.